# Answering the same question across the site

Tags: discussion

These three questions are essentially the same:

[UICollectionView - Horizontal paging with 3 pages visible and 1 in the middle using UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524304/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-with-3-pages-visible-and-1-in-the-middle-us/16071405#16071405)

[UICollectionView: paging like Safari tabs or App Store search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919457/uicollectionview-paging-like-safari-tabs-or-app-store-search/16070570#16070570)

[UICollectionView, paging, and clipsToBounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817960/uicollectionview-paging-and-clipstobounds)

I found a good solution for it, blogged, and answered all three of these questions with the same post. Two of those were deleted, so I'm assuming it's bad form to answer multiple questions with the same answer.

What is the proper way to help people who've asked the same question in a different place?

Also, why was the answer with one upvote deleted, leaving one with no upvotes?

Comment: If all questions can be answered with the same answer, why not mark them as duplicates of one of them?

Comment: @Bart Because of "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"

Comment: @hjpotter92 Then, as the author of an answer, add your excellent answer, get upvotes for it and flag/vote for the closure of the dupes.

Comment: @Bart In the meantime, people don't have answers to questions, though.

Comment: That's unfortunate then. They should ideally not have asked duplicate questions to begin with though. And one not having any answers is no excuse there either.

Comment: These do seem like duplicate questions to me, but given the `ios` tag I'm reluctant to just close them without some more people voting first.

Comment: I've flagged them as dupes, it wasn't apparent to me how to do that at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...so I'm assuming it's bad form to answer multiple questions with the same answer.

Yes, if you can copy/paste the same answer to multiple questions, then the questions are either duplicates or you should be customizing your answers to fit the specific questions that are asked.

> What is the proper way to help people who've asked the same question in a different place?

If the questions are duplicates then you should answer one of them, then vote to close, flag for a moderator to close, and/or leave a comment on the others with a link to the original (answered) question so other members of the community will vote to close.

> Also, why was the answer with one upvote deleted, leaving one with no upvotes?

That's just due to the way duplicates are flagged.  When you copy/paste your answers, the later copies are the ones removed, regardless of voting.